# Permutation representation, understanding a general definition and apply it to $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Author of a course I read define a permutation representation this way :

> Let $X$ be a finite set , and $G$ acting on $X$ (there exists an action of $G$
> on $X$, let's note it $*$). We associate to it a permutation
> representation on the vectorial space $V=\oplus_{x\in
> X}\mathbb{C}e_x$.
>
> Then, $G$ acts on $V$ ($V$ is a representation of $G$), by:  $$g.e_x=e_{g*x}$$

1. Firstly in this definition, can someone try to define $e_x$? I thought we were considering the elements $x_i$ of $X$ as a basis of $\mathbb{C}X$, so why are these $e_x$ appearing?
2. Application on $S_3$ : What confuses me a lot is this example the author gives :

> $S_3$ acts naturally on $X=\left\{1,2,3\right\}$. According to the precedent
> definition/proposition, $S_3$ acts on $\mathbb {C^3}$ by permutation
> of canonical basis vectors $\left\{e_1,e_2,e_3\right\}$.

What I don't understand is that, for me $V=\oplus_{x\in X}\mathbb{C}e_x=\mathbb{C}X=\left\{c_1+2c_2+3c_3, c_k\in \mathbb{C}\right\}$ and I don't relate it to a cartesian product. Maybe if someone writes me exactly what are $e_1,e_2,e_3$ in this specific case I'll understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the set $\{e_x\mid x\in X\}$ is a basis of the vector space $\Bbb C X$.

Concrete sense:

Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$. You can write the space as $V={\Bbb C}^n$, where the element $x_i$ corresponds to the $i$th unit vector $e_i$.

Abstract sense:

A general element of this space can be written as $\sum_{x\in X} c_x e_x$ or even $\sum_{x\in X} c_x x$, where $c_x\in\Bbb C$. The latter representation is used in the example.

Comment: Concerning the concrete sense : In this case , if $x_i$ corresponds to the ith unit vector , what's the difference with choosing another X space if each time we got the same unit vectors ? What i mean is , i don't understand what is changing when switching from X={$x_1,...,x_n$} to Y={$y_1,...,y_n$} for example. I don't know if i'm clear , if not tell me , i'll try to say it differently. And , in the abstract sense , isn't it the first writing that is used in the example ?(i mean , not the latter,?)

Comment: And why aren't the elements x of X a basis of CX? Maybe there is a definition i don't understand well...

Comment: In the abstract case, $X$ can serve as a basis as in the text.